# JavaScript nested functions : how to avoid loops

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am creating a little javascript/jQuery application with differents steps.
For that I am using a js file with different functions.

At the top of the file I call my first function.
Inside my first function I call a second function when clicking on a button.
Inside the second function I'd like to call back the first one, but "outside" the second one : I mean I don't want the first function to be run inside the second one, because of looping effects...

```
myFirstFunction();

function myFirstFunction() {

    // some code

    $('myButton').click(function() {
        mySecondFunction();
    }

}

function mySecondFunction() {

    // some code

    $('myOtherButton').click(function() {
        myFirstFunction();
    }

}
```

I don't know if this is possible, may be I'd better use objects or else, but I'm pretty new to Javascript...
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you probably want to remove the button click event $('myButton').off('click') in each one of those callbacks so that way when the button is clicked it won't call both events...

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind event handlers inside other event handlers. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: There's no looping here. These functions just bind event handlers that call the other function, they don't call the other function directly.

Comment: If you want to alternate what happens when you click on the button, use a single event handler. It can check and set a variable that controls which action it performs.

Comment: @Barmar I gotta many forms in one html file, I show only one at once. The first function show the first form and once validated, the form is hidden and the second form is showed. The button calling the first function is actually a "previous" button : it hides the second form and show back the first one

Comment: So are there actually two different buttons, a "previous" button and a "next" button?

Comment: yes, sorry may be I should have told that before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single event handler there:

```
var handler = myFirstFunction;

$('myButton').click(function() { handler(); });

function myFirstFunction() { handler = mySecondFunction; }
function mySecondFunction() { handler = myFirstFunction; }
```

That handler will call either one of your functions.

Update: Or if these are two distinct buttons then

```
$('myButton').click( mySecondFunction );
$('myOtherButton').click( myFirstFunction );
```

Comment: Thank you c-smile, but the buttons are actually not the same (sorry that's my fault, I edited my post...)

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it's good to avoid nesting functions within eachother for reasons that you mentioned it might get messy. I'm sure somebody else can weight in, but if you want to stick in vanilla JS i would create a variable that you modify the state of and have a conditional statement determine what function to run.

```
var state = 1;

function handler(){
    if(state == 1){
        myFirstFunction();
        state = 2;
    }
    else if(state == 2){
        mySecondFunction();
        state = 1;
    }
}
```

Then have your myButton execute the handler() function.